# LiveBroadcasts: list: The request use of mine not supported

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

I am trying to integrate a notifications module in my app that will notify users, if there is a live stream on one of the curated channels (owned by other youtube users, not me).

While checking the API documentation I have found this page:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list#try-it

While trying out how the API works, I have entered the following request parameters.

[image request parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ5eu.png)

By the way, the channel that I have entered is random live channels that I have found on Youtube Live. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZNbHKwdcl9KheS09yurKxQ

The response that I got, is this:

[image response 400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weaFA.png)

> The request use of mine not supported.

What am I doing wrong here?